# Jquery Mobile center and use full width of screen with 3 buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to get 3 buttons to use full width of screen and re-size if needed. However when I try to use my code it won't center. Tried using margin-left margin-right auto on buttons but seems i cannot get it to work.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="overview-content">
<div id="navgroup" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <button class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a ui-icon-star">Aktivitet</button>
    <button class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a ui-icon-home">Grupp</button>
    <button class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a ui-icon-mail">Meddelande</button>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#navgroup {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

#overview-content {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.ui-controlgroup-controls {
    width: 100%;

}

.ui-controlgroup-horizontal .ui-controlgroup-controls button.ui-btn,
.ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-btn-icon-notext {
    width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Where do you use "ui-controlgroup-controls" CSS class ?

Comment: Its added by jquery mobile during init automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To center the buttons you'll want to make them block level elements, and then to give them a responsive width you'll give the buttons a percentage for width- see below:

```
button {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: It wont apply to the buttons for some reason, think I tried that but with inline-block.

Thing is, i want the 3 buttons always take full screen-space.

Comment: You won't want to use inline-block unless you want them side-by-side. Check out my CSS addition here: http://jsfiddle.net/TLmav/

Comment: I want them side by side with a controlgroup, I tried to use a 3 block grid from the http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/content/content-grids.html

Comment: I got it working by using grid layout from JQM but I still have no idea how to use it with controlgroup

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your CSS to

```
#navgroup {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
.ui-controlgroup-controls {
    width: 500px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.ui-controlgroup-horizontal .ui-controlgroup-controls button.ui-btn, .ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-btn-icon-notext {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/w42PU/2/)**

The border-box rule makes sure border and padding are included within the element widths when sizing. So each button takes one third of the ui-controlgroup-controls container and that container is given a set width. When the screen is wider than the set width, it is centered by your text-align: center rule, and when the screen is narrower, the max-width rule keeps it within the page.